# Ajax form submittion in wordpress without page reloading always give me the following error: 400 bad request

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am building a custom template in WordPress and I want to handle form submission using Ajax without page reloading and I always have the following error on my console 400 bad request. The form is not submitting to the server in other to handle the request. I have tried many possibilities but I didn't succeed.

**Bellow is the form,is an image upload form**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
   <div class="Success-div"></div>
      <p> Vous devez nous fournir un certificat médical valide attestant vos aptitudes à 
       faire partir du club et faire part aux activités du club:</p>
      <p class="statusMsg"></p>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="tel">Certificat médical</label><a style= "color:#DAA520;" href="#" 
 id="effectuerTest"> (je ne possède pas un certificat médical)</a>
    <input type="file" name="certificatMedicalMajeur" class="form-control" 
 id="CertificatMedicalfichier" accept="application/pdf" required/>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="certificat-majeur-submit" id="submitbtn" class="certificat- 
   majeur-submit btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Enregistrer" />
</form>
```

**Ajax code TO send the submitted data to the server**

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.certificat-majeur-submit', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
var file_data =  $('#CertificatMedicalfichier').prop('files')[0];
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('file', file_data);
var $this = $(this);
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      data:form_data,
      action: 'post_md_support_save'
    },
    url: ajaxurl,
    processData : false,
    success: function (response) {
        jQuery('.Success-div').html(data.message);
    },  
    error: function (response) {
      console.log("error form");
    }
    });
});
```

**And finally this is the code to handle the request file in function.php**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_post_md_support_save', 'md_abonnements_save' );

add_action( 'wp_ajax_post_md_support_save', 'md_abonnements_save' );

function md_abonnements_save(){

    echo "ajax responding";
    die();
}
```

Comment: you've to add your action where the form should go in order to submit the page. in your case it'll be the page where you're pasting this form.

Comment: I have added my action in the file even like that is still not working. The form is inside a file I have included in my template. I have included the file in the template using the get_template_part() function

Comment: Maybe this can help you in developing the ajax form: http://regularcoder.com/tutorial/submit-form-using-ajax-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this code in Front End of your website, you should also add nopriv action hook:  add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_post_md_support_save', 'md_abonnements_save' );